# How do I read HttpEntity without consuming it?

Tags: java, android, httpresponse

I've got `org.apache.http.HttpResponse` object, which I'm using at different places in the code. One of those places is for logging.

The problem is that when I run following log code:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
try {
    String content = Base64.encodeToString(
            EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity), Base64.DEFAULT);
    sb.append(content + "\r\n");
} catch (Exception e) {
    sb.append("\r\n\r\n====EXCEPTION=====\r\n" + e.toString()
            + "\r\n");
}
```

and than I try to read entry content in the actual processing code, that causes the code to throw following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
```

My question is: how do I read the entity without consuming it in the log code?

**UPDATE**
here's the full code of the function I use to transform httpresponse to string:

```
static String toString(org.apache.http.HttpResponse response) {
    try {
        if (response == null) {
            return "null";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("==============BEGIN HttpResponse================\r\n");
        StatusLine sl = response.getStatusLine();
        if (sl == null) {
            sb.append("status line is null\r\n");
        } else {
            sb.append(String.format("%s %s\r\n", sl.getStatusCode(),
                    sl.getReasonPhrase()));
        }

        for (Header h : response.getAllHeaders()) {
            if (h == null) {
                sb.append("header is null\r\n");
                continue;
            }
            sb.append(String.format("%s: %s\r\n", h.getName(), h.getValue()));
        }

        sb.append("\r\r\r\n");

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity == null) {
            sb.append("content is null");
        } else {
            try {
                String content = Base64.encodeToString(
                        EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity), Base64.DEFAULT);

                sb.append(content + "\r\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sb.append("\r\n\r\n====EXCEPTION=====\r\n" + e.toString()
                        + "\r\n");
            }
        }

        sb.append("\r\n==============END HttpResponse================\r\n");

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code before "response.getEntity();"

Comment: you could try to `mark` the entity inputstream, and then reset it, but I am not sure it is actually markable

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So what I ended up doing is implementing my own HttpEntity class, and than just using  `response.setEntity(...)` to replace the previous entity. That class stores the result as binary array and returns it as many times as necessary.

Comment: How to do the same for request? I want to log request body and its content-type can be anything (json, plain-text, multipart/formdata etc).

Answer (score 1):

It might give you some performance issues, but will work:
Example of my HttpClient with logging.

```
private CloseableHttpResponse invoke(HttpRequestBase http) {
        try {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(http);
            if (http instanceof HttpPost) {
                InputStream inputStream = ((HttpPost) http).getEntity().getContent();
                String body = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, Charset.defaultCharset());

                HttpEntity respBody = response.getEntity();
                String responseBody = StreamUtils.copyToString(respBody.getContent(), Charset.defaultCharset());
                response.setEntity(new StringEntity(responseBody));
                LOG.info(String.format("Sending request: [%s] %s => [%s] \nPayload:\n%s \nResponse:\n%s", http.getMethod(), http.getURI(), response.getStatusLine(), body, responseBody));
            } else {
                LOG.info(String.format("Sending request: [%s] %s => [%s]", http.getMethod(), http.getURI(), response.getStatusLine()));
            }
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("HTTP request failed: " + http.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

Main idea is following:
1. make http call
2. copy to string your response body:

```
 HttpEntity respBody = response.getEntity();  
 String responseBody = StreamUtils.copyToString(respBody.getContent(), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

3. log it
4. set new response entity like `response.setEntity(new StringEntity(responseBody));`

This example work good for small test framework, not sure it's good code for production application